# using SQLiteWinRTPhone inside a portable class library for windows phone 8

Tags: sqlite, dll, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I am using **[SQLiteWinRTPhone](http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)** wrapper for implementing database in my app.

However when I tried to use the same wrapper inside a portable class library project I am not able to use it.

I have read somewhere that we cannot use SQLite inside the portable class libraries. what can be solution/alternative for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Go thorough bellow link

[Windows Phone 7 Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)

[SQLite-WinRT: Database programming on Windows Phone and Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx)

[How to use SQLite in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)

Hope it will help you

Comment: I think you didnt understood my question, I want to use the SQLite in the portable class library not in a app project.

Comment: okey sorry but i think its not possible because we have to import .sqlite file in our project and how can i import .sqlite file in to portable library

Comment: I have also read that, I am just seeking for the alternative solutions for using the SQLite in PCLs because that what I want to achieve finally (Accessing Database through PCL from my app).

Comment: whats your aim to make portable library so i can give you some suggestion.whats you definition for making portable library

Comment: I just wanted to write some wrappers for the app developer, so that he can include the portable clsss library developed by me and access the db from the app thus hiding the complexities from the developer and will also be east to share

Comment: its good idea... you can do with web service also but you have use dll than i think we need to some RND... i am trying to find best solution when ever i got i ll post it